# where clause on include column using sequilize

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm using this query:

```
db.Spectrum.findAll({
        attributes: ['title', [db.Sequelize.fn('SUM', db.Sequelize.col('quantity') ), 'count']],
        include: [
            {model: db.Varietal,
             attributes : ['specID', 'id'],
                include : [
                    { model : db.Wine,
                      required: false,
                      attributes : ['varietal_id', 'id'], 
                      where : {restaurant_id : restaurant_id,
                                owner_id : null} }
                ],
            }
        ],
        group : ['specID']
    })
```

Which gives me the correct results, the problem is because it ands the where clause to the left join it runs really slow (about 2 seconds).

The raw query of the left join looks like this.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `wines` AS `Varietals.Wines` ON `Varietals`.`id` = `Varietals.Wines`.`varietal_id` AND `Varietals.Wines`.`restaurant_id` = 16 AND `Varietals.Wines`.`owner_id` IS NULL
```

I would like the query to have the left join and a where clause like this..

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `wines` AS `Varietals.Wines` ON `Varietals`.`id` = `Varietals.Wines`.`varietal_id`
WHERE `Varietals.Wines`.`restaurant_id` = 16 AND `Varietals.Wines`.`owner_id` IS NULL
```

But everything I try puts 'Spectrum' before it and then doesn't find the row. How is this suppose to be done? Or am I going to have to just use a raw query?

Answer (score 7):

`include.where` will always add the condition to the join.
However in Sequelize `v3.13.0` support for special nested keys were added.

It's now possible to add a where object to the toplevel object containing dot seperated keys wrapped in $ to specify it being a nested field.

Applying it to your code:

```
db.Spectrum.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: db.Varietal,
      include : [
        {
          model : db.Wine
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  where: {
    '$Varietals.Wines.restaurant_id$': restaurant_id,
    '$Varietals.Wines.owner_id$': null
  },
  group : ['specID']
});
```

(I removed a few statements to focus on the important part)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this feature! When I try to implement this though it gives me ```WHERE `Varietals`.`Wines`.`restaurant_id` = 16``` Which gives me "Unknown column" error since it looks like it either needs to read ```WHERE `Varietals.Wines`.`restaurant_id` = 16``` ?

Comment: Ah you're right, that might be tricky to fix at the moment actually, if you do need the where to be on the outer.

Answer (score 3):

## Include array

```
     include = [{
        model: db.caregiverCategory,
        as: 'categories',
        attributes: ['name'],
        required: true,
        attributes: ['name'],
        include: [{
            model: db.category,
            as: 'category',
            required: true
        }]
    }]
```

## Where Clause

```
    where[Op.or] = [{
        '$categories.name$': { [Op.like]: '%' + query.category_name + '%' }
   }, {
        '$categories.category.name$': { [Op.like]: '%' + query.category_name + '%' }
    }]
```

## You need to add all fields like name (which are required in or) in attributes: ['name'] otherwise it will give unknowm columns error.

Comment: You need to add all fields like name... what if i want to use them in my where stm but do not want to select them